# SCVMM 2008 R2 problems migrating VM from VS2005 to Hyper-V host

Tags: hyper-v-server-2008-r2, scvmm, microsoft-virtual-server

I have System Center Virtual Machine Manager 2008 R2 installed, and have a Hyper-V R2 host and a Virtual Server 2005 host.  I'm trying to migrate my machines from the VS2005 host to the Hyper-V host, and keep getting the following error...

> VMM is unable to complete the
>   requested file transfer. The
>   connection to the HTTP server
>   myserver.mydomain.local could
>   not be established.   (Unknown error
>   (0x80072efd))
>
> Recommended Action Ensure that the
>   HTTP service and/or the agent on the
>   machine myserver.mydomain.local
>   are installed and running and that a
>   firewall is not blocking HTTPS
>   traffic.

(Note - migrations between Hyper-V hosts managed by the VMM server work fine - my problem is just going from VS2005->Hyper-V hosts)

I have no firewalls turned on on either of the servers, and no firewalls in the middle.  I've looked all over for answers to this problem, and am getting nowhere.  All the articles I find when searching are talking about either V2V or P2V - and i'm just trying to do a straight migrate VM.

I've tried rebooting the boxes, changing the BITS SSL port number, restarting services, triple-checking firewalls, etc.

Does anyone have any good suggestions as to how I can resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I've read that it is supported too but never had any luck with it, myself. Sorry I'm no help there. Instead, I had to do this to migrate VMs from VS2005 to Hyper-V:

1. Uninstall the integration bits from the VM on VS2005. Plan this out because you lose mouse control.
2. Shut down VM in VS2005.
3. Create new VM with the same CPU, memory, name, and no disks in Hyper-V.
4. Copy the VHD file(s) from VS2005 to the new VM directory on the Hyper-V server.
5. Edit the VM in Hyper-V to point to the VHD file(s).
6. Start the VM in Hyper-V and immediately install the integration bits.

This isn't anything magical - a VM in VS2005 and Hyper-V is simply made up of an XML config file and the VHD files. Moving a VM manually like this works fine between VS2005 and Hyper-V and also between Hyper-V servers when you either don't have SCVMM or can't for some reason use the Hyper-V import/export feature (it does seem to fail sometimes). I've actually found that learning how to do a manual move is a good practice - you learn a lot about how things work under the hood so you are better able to deal with emergencies.

I know this isn't the solution you were looking for and you can probably find more comprehensive explanations of manual moves via Google, but perhaps it will be of some assistance. Good luck.

Comment: OK, this is embarassing. I read this answer and thought it was good so was going to add my two cents to agree and then after I posted my comment realized I wrote this. I didn't recall doing that. So now I'm editing my comment wherein I agreed with myself to admit I'm a fool instead.

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe this is supported in SCVMM.  Perhaps this article might help:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd296684(WS.10).aspx

Comment: according to this page - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.10.vmm.aspx - its supported.  "Finally, VMM 2008 can migrate an existing Virtual Server 2005 VM onto a Hyper-V host, automatically performing all the upgrades and conversions needed for migration."